# SQL two tables relation

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, designer

I've got a problem with two tables which I thought is straight forward and turn out it's not.
Table 1 (Word):

```
WordID - key
WordValue string
...
```

Table 2 (Sentence):

```
SentenceID - key
SentenceValue String
WordKey int
```

I need that one word has several sentences. So I set the relation in VS C# DataSet Designer. After I start the program I got the child table with red circles with exclamation marks and messages ForeignKeyConstraint WordSentence requires the child key value (30) to exist in the parent table. But I have several WordKey=30 and one WordId = 30. So as I understand I have a child with a key and the parent also has this value in ID field = 30 and 1 but don't have anything in a parent table although my structure looks like in Northwind database.

Comment: I think you might want a MANY-to-MANY table here rather, as a sentence can have more than 1 word, and a word can belong to more than 1 sentence.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: No it's not cuz a program is for learning words and sentences are examples for a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers. My problem was a bit silly cuz I needed the easiest way to deal with two tables in a database and wanted to present them with standard way C# and VS give (just carrying and dropping tables to a form and attach a navigator). So in my case **I had two tables with a relationship 1 to many and needed so that when focus is on a record N  of a parent table only some set of records could be seen in a child table.** Instead I saw all of them in both parent and child tables. And when I set a relationship through a "Edit DataSet with Designer" I got an error.

**Now a solution to this problem:** as it stated in the book "Beginning Microsoft Visual C# 2008" and many other online sources, you create a data connection with a DB and create a DataSet. Then you drag tables you need to a form. **But if you want a correct dependence so only particular set of records was seen in a child table but not all of them you need to drag a subtable in the DataSource window in VS!!!** Like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Though not directly addresses your problem as I am not really sure if I understood the issue correctly but given the problem statement, IMHO a better design for this could be this:

Table 1 (Word)

```
WordID - Primary Key
WordValue - String
...
```

Table 2 (Sentence)

```
SentenceID - Primary Key
SentenceValue - String
...
```

Table 3 (WordSentenceMap)

```
WordID (Foreign Key to Word)
SentenceID (Foreign Key to Sentence)
```

This way, one word can be used in multiple sentences and at the same time, one sentence can be used as an example for multiple words.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll use it in the program.